# Font size conflict between iOS and Hybrid app

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework, fonts, font-size

I have created a native iOS app a year ago, for most of the Heading title I had given the font size as **System Bold 17.0**

Now am developing a hybrid application for the same product and am using the same font size as **font-size: 17pt**

I believe the measurement in native iOS app is done as points which is same as hybrid, in that case, why does the hybrid app sizes looks little bigger than the native iOS font size ??
Am I missing something here ? Please help me

Comment: Do you use the exact same font?

Comment: @Sebastian, yes. font-family: -apple-system;

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

1px = 1pt

I did all the inspection and they are the same now.